# GUI for MongoDB in Unix

Tags: gratis, gui, mongodb, unix

I need a GUI client that:

- Works on Unix
- Is free
- Supports documents editing

Is there an app which satisfies these requirements?

Comment: Are web-based UIs OK? If yes I am afraid there are too many... If not please mention it, thanks.

Comment: probably an interesting site: http://mongodb-tools.com/

Answer (score 0):

#### Robo 3T

[Robo 3T](https://www.robomongo.org/), formerly Robomongo, (Windows/Mac/Linux) is the free lightweight GUI for MongoDB enthusiasts.

- GUI for MongoDB with embedded shell

Robo 3T is packaged as a snap package (*robo3t-snap*) in Ubuntu, and the same snap package can also be installed in most major Linux distributions if snapd is also installed. To install Robo 3T in Debian-based distributions open the terminal and type:

```
sudo snap install robo3t-snap
```

#### Studio 3T

Are you serious about MongoDB? Choose [Studio 3T](https://www.robomongo.org/) (Windows/Mac/Linux), the professional GUI and IDE for MongoDB, and save hours per week. Studio 3T is available in Core, Pro, and Enterprise editions. The Core edition is always free for non-commercial use.

- Autocomplete queries with IntelliShell
- Drag and drop fields to visually build queries
- Use SQL to query MongoDB
- Build aggregation queries stage by stage
- Generate driver code in 5 languages
- Multiple ways to import & export, including SQL migration
- Automate repetitive MongoDB tasks like imports
- And so much more...